# Unknown certificate issuer with startcomca.com

Tags: ssl, certificate

I'm going mad about my SSL certificate renewal.
Here is the thing : I freshly created new certificates (.key, .csr, and all that stuff from https://www.startcomca.com/).
I configured my apache web server to match the configuration files :

```
SSLCertificateFile        /etc/ssl/private/2_myhiddendomain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile     /etc/ssl/private/myhiddendomain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile   /etc/ssl/private/1_root_bundle.crt
```

I mean, all is working well. The certificates are well placed, and well installed, everything is correct and working, as I can see on the very useful tool : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

But here comes the point, when I try to access the website from any browser (FF, Safari, Chrome), the browser security tells me :

```
Your connection is not secure
The owner of www.myhiddendomain.com has configured their website improperly.
To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

www.myhiddendomain.com uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates.
An additional root certificate may need to be imported.
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

I really think the problem is either the intermediate certificate, or the root certificate, which could be un-properly set. I don't know how to "make my cert trusted". I understand the problem, but can't find any solution to make it work.

4 hours of investigations seems not to be enough, so if anybody could help :-)
Thanks !

Comment: In short: use a different CA. StartSSL is no longer considered trusted by major browsers.

Comment: WOW... Thank you so much....

Comment: I used https://certbot.eff.org/ and all worked well...... I lost so much time for that... Thank you !